# How to increase the size of text that dynamically created in java

Tags: java, html, xml, dom

I have code where it reads the XML file and display. i am able to size of the content for the cells in td, but how to change the size of texts where td cells are dynamically created. Here is the code.

### Code:

```
public class ticketcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
        String content = "";
        String content1 ="<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><TABLE border=3>";
        FileWriter fw =null;
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        String Path = "src";
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\file.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);
                if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) varNode;
                    NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                    NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");
                    Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                    Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);
                    if (teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                        && impNode.getNodeType() ==
                    Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element teamElement = (Element) teamNode;
                        Element impElement = (Element) impNode;
                        ticket ticket = new ticket(
                        teamElement.getTextContent(),
                        impElement.getTextContent());
                        ticketList.add(ticket);
                    }
                }
                File file = new File(Path + "\\result1.html");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<ticket, Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
        for (ticket c : ticketList)
            if (!count.containsKey(c))
                count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));
            List<String> imps = getimps(count);
            List<String> teams = getteams(count);
            content=content+"<tr><th>ticket</th> ";
            for (String s : imps) {
                content=content+"<th>"+s+"</th>";
            }
            content=content+"</tr>";
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            for (String m : teams) {
                System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
                content = content + "<tr><td><font size = 5>" + m + "</font></td>"
                + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";
            }
            bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
            bw.close();
            Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String url = Path + "//result1.html";
            // String url = "C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html";//"D:/hi.html";
            String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
            File htmlFile = new File(url);
            System.out.println(url);
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());
            // Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
            // pc.waitFor();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html");
        }

        private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
            List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
                if (!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
                    teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
                return teams;
            }

            private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps,
            Map<ticket, Integer>
            count) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String v : imps) {
                    Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
                    if (cnt == null) {
                        cnt = 0;
                    }
                    builder.append("<td>"+cnt + "</td>");
                }
                return builder.toString();
            }

            private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
                List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
                    if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
                        imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
                    return imps;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Here i am posting specific code where i need help.

Comment: for (String m : teams) {
            System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
            content = content + "<tr><td><font size = 5>" + m + "</font></td>"
                    + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";
        }
        bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
        bw.close();
I need to set size for the getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) which is generate dynamically

Comment: opened new question..use this content = content + "<tr><td><font size=6>" + m + "</td></font>"
                    + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";

Comment: replace the 5 in "<font size = 5>" with whatever value you prefer?

Comment: i tried this but font size is applied only to the values M not to the getNumOfteams(m, imps, count)

Comment: getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) is creating new td's with counts for this font size is not applying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
package com.sof.test;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ticketcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
        String content = "";
        String content1 ="<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><TABLE border=3>";
        FileWriter fw =null;
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        String Path = "src";


        try {



            File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\ticket.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);

                if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                    NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                    NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");

                    Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                    Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);

                    if (teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                            && impNode.getNodeType() ==

                            Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element teamElement = (Element) teamNode;
                        Element impElement = (Element) impNode;
                        ticket ticket = new ticket(
                                teamElement.getTextContent(),

                                impElement.getTextContent());
                        ticketList.add(ticket);
                    }
                }


                File file = new File(Path + "\\result1.html");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                 fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                 bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<ticket, Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
        for (ticket c : ticketList)
            if (!count.containsKey(c))
                count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));

        List<String> imps = getimps(count);

        List<String> teams = getteams(count);


        content=content+"<tr><th>ticket</th> ";
        for (String s : imps) {

            content=content+"<th>"+s+"</th>";
        }

        content=content+"</tr>";

        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        for (String m : teams) {
            System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
            content = content + "<tr><td> <font size=6>" + m + "</font></td>" + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";

        }
        bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
        bw.close();

        Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String url = Path + "//result1.html";
        // String url = "C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html";//"D:/hi.html";
        String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
        File htmlFile = new File(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

        // Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
        // pc.waitFor();

        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html");
    }

    private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
                teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
        return teams;
    }

    private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps,
            Map<ticket, Integer>

            count) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String v : imps) {
            Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
            if (cnt == null) {
                cnt = 0;
            }
            builder.append("<td><font size=10>"+cnt + "</font></td>");

        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
                imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
        return imps;
    }
}
```

output

[image]

source code of html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<TABLE border=3>
    <tr>
        <th>ticket</th>
        <th>I2</th>
        <th>I1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=6>b</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>1</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>0</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=6>c</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>0</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>1</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=6>A</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>1</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>4</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><font size=6>B</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>1</font></td>
        <td><font size=10>0</font></td>
    </tr>
</TABLE>
</HTML>
```

Comment: if i use above one also no luck. font size applies to m not for count. if appears like in HTML view source.<tr><td><font size = 6>TEAM A</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>77</td></font></tr>

Comment: Am not getting u exactly.. look the updated code above with html... am applying for both ticket column and I2 and I1 column... not for count means ?? how u want ??

Comment: i got it now. i used on java script for refreshing the browser. String content = "";
        String content1 ="<HTML><HEAD>";
        content1 = content1 + "<script type=\"text/JavaScript\">";
        content1 = content1 + "function timerefresh(timeoutPeriod) { setTimeout(\"location.reload(true);\",timeoutPeriod);}</script>";

Comment: but after every 5 min it stops refreshing and will be as blank page any reason behing that or scripting is wrong

Comment: google it and try ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865827/how-do-i-frequently-refresh-a-specific-web-page-using-php  and http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/49680-refresh-page-specific-time-day.html  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time

Comment: can you help me on one more issue..  i stucked..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421593/need-to-send-mail-based-on-condition-of-element-in-xml